# Java modulus if number on left is smaller than number on right?

Tags: java, math, operators

What would (0 + 1) % 10? return? How do you deal with numbers on the left being smaller than numbers on the right? How is this even possible?

Comment: The modulus returns the remainder of a division. How does 1 divided by 10 leave a remainder of 1?

Comment: The result of the divistion is zero remainder one.

Comment: @user1937198 Can you explain that a little further? I don't quite understand how that's happening. I'll give you a check if you can help me understand it please.

Comment: @Jake i'm asking a question from you.you have 10 balls .now you have to divide it to 10 childrens .after that how much ball left?? it's zero. well think you have 1 ball and you have to  distribute it to 10 children alike.then how much ball have you left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modulo is the remainder of an integer division. Say you have integers a and b.

```
n = a / b (integer), and
m = a % b = a - ( b * n )
```

Then

```
b * n + m = a
```

Examples:

```
 a    b    n = a/b  b * n  m = a%b
 0    5      0        0      0    
 1    5      0        0      1
 2    5      0        0      2
 3    5      0        0      3
 4    5      0        0      4
 5    5      1        5      0
 6    5      1        5      1
....
10    5      2       10      0
12    5      2       10      2
```

etc.

Basically, the integer division determines how many times b fully fits inside a. If b < a, that's zero times. The modulo operation then returns what is left. If b < a, that's a.

Answer (score 0):

`(0 + 1) % 10` would return 1
What is making you confused about small and large numbers in an expression?

Comment: What would (1 + 1) % 10 return?

Comment: But HOW! I want to know how it's 2 and how it's 1.

Comment: @Jake Try google first http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html, http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/273783-the-use-of-the-modulo-operator/, this was the first search hit

Comment: @SamTebbs33 I know how it works for values on the right side that are bigger than the values on the left... I'm asking how does 1 % 10  (The division of which equals 0.10) equal to a remainder of 1? The math isn't making any sense.

Comment: @Jake / and % is different